# mpu6050 CONFIG register

Tags: filter, mpu6050

To enable low pass filter in mpu6050 the the first three bits [0:2] have to be modified in CONFIG register (0x1A) according to the required cutoff frequency. How to set/reset that particular bits? Already 255 is stored in that register (1111 1111) can I use (11111111 & 11110101) for example. But bit 6 and 7 are reserved.  Is this ok?  Any other method to enable low pass filter?

Comment: I have interfaced mpu6050 to arduino uno.